# Input to a file in an array and then pulling info from file later in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to get a program built for a class project and just need help understanding a concept and how it should work. I need to do this:

At the end of each game, the program asks you to record the scores for each team member. You type in their first name and that person's score for the game on a single line. Should print the lists into columns of name and scores entered, highest score to lowest score and alphabetical order.

My issue is that if I go in and write a file and put the information in, I can pull from that file correctly but I can't get a user input into a file and then pull from that. If anyone could help me understand that. Sorry this is kinda long.

```html
# Input trying to figure out
scoring = []
n = int(input("Enter the amount: "))
print("Write the name followed by a ',' and then the score")
with open("scores.txt", 'w') as the_file:
    for i in range(0, n):
        name = input("Enter the Name: ")
        score = input("Enter the Score: ")
        name = the_file.write(name)
        score = the_file.write(score)

# output
scores = []
with open("scores.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, score = line.split(',')
        score = int(score)
        scores.append((name, score))

list.sort(scores, reverse=True, key=lambda s: s[1])
```

Comment: So whats this code doing?

Comment: I am supposed to get a user input for a bowling program in this assignment. Take user input until you decide to stop and then write them to a file. Also be able to pull them from a file in sorted lists (alphabetical, how they were entered and highest score)

Comment: So i would collect the names/scores in a list, and then write the whole list to the file once you are done

Comment: I have a hard time with that. I have been having to teach myself everything and am fuzzy on that. The professor I have had has been a little everywhere and hard for me at least to follow

Answer (score 0):

You do not write the format that you expect when reading the file:

```
name = input("Enter the Name: ")
score = input("Enter the Score: ")
# do not assign the return value of the write function
the_file.write('{},{}\n'.format(name, score))
```

Comment: Alright! Thanks, that makes a lot more sense actually. I have a hard time writing it but easy to understand when I can see it. How would you do multiple sorted lists for different columns?